# Pattern matching on nested arrays in Scala

Tags: scala, types, pattern-matching

I want to create array of `Any` type, which looks like:

```
val arr: Array[Any] = Array(Array(1, 2, Array(3)), 4)
```

Then I want to make it flatten using tail recursion with this code:

```
def flatten(xs: Array[Any]): Array[Any] = {

    @tailrec
    def makeFlat(xs: List[Any], res: List[Any]): List[Any] = xs match {
      case Nil => res
      case head :: tail => head match {
        case h: Array[Any] => makeFlat(h.toList ::: tail, res)
        case _ => makeFlat(tail, res :+ head)
      }
    }

    makeFlat(xs.toList, Nil).toArray
}
```

I'm using Scala 2.12 version.

When iteration comes to internal array `Array(3)` from source array, pattern matching `case h: Array[Any]` is not working. This is strange, because `Int` extends `Any`. I've tried to debug and realized that this array is `int[1]` (array of primitive int).

Why scala decided to make it as primitive array and how I can figure out this case?

Comment: Scala infers the type of the Array(3) as Array[Int], since you are only storing an Int in it. Your type of Array[Any] only refers to the top-level array. val arr: Array[Any] = Array(Array(1, 2, Array[Any](3)), 4) will create an Array[Any] for Array(3).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not working because you're not letting it infer the type.

Replace `case h: Array[Any]` with `case h: Array[_]` and you're golden.

Answer (score 0):

`Array` is a java class, not scala class

It doesn't support variances

See http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/variances.html

Comment: Really? But I read about `Array` class in scala documentation. Please check this link http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/Array.html.

Comment: its runtime class is java class, all additional member function is translated at compile time. and the most important, it is defined as `Array[T]` not `Array[+T]`